# conditional replacement between two data.frames by colnames and variables in R

Tags: replace, conditional-statements

I am trying to replace the values of a dataframe by the values of a variable from another dataframe based on matching colnames from the first one. I was digging around and found some lines of code but the output is not the expected

```
data<-data.frame(ASV10=c(0,0,1,0,0),ASV78=c(1,0,0,0,0),ASV34=c(0,0,0,0,1))
data2<-data.frame(var=c("ASV78","ASV10","ASV34"),trat=c("A","B","C"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I would like to change numerical values of data in that way: if 0 change to NA if is higher than 0 to the corresponding value of trat in data2

First I changed all 0 values in data to NA

```
data[data == 0] <- NA
```

Then I sorted data by its names and data2 by var (it has same values than names(data))

```
data<-data[,sort(names(data))]
data2 <- data2[order(data2$var),]
```

Then I tried to change values of data that are not NA by values of data2$trat

```
data[match(colnames(data),data2$var)]<-ifelse(is.na(data),NA,data2$trat)
```

However I get

```
  ASV10 ASV34 ASV78
1  <NA>  <NA>     C
2  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
3     A  <NA>  <NA>
4  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
5  <NA>     B  <NA>
```

It works partially. Respects NA places,replacing non 0 values, but values of data2$trat do not
correspond between colnames(data) and data2$var

```
  ASV10 ASV34 ASV78
1  <NA>  <NA>     A
2  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
3     B  <NA>  <NA>
4  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
5  <NA>     C  <NA>
```

What can it be wrong?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to get what I want with the following lines

```
    w <- which(data>0,arr.ind=TRUE)
data[w] <- names(data)[w[,"col"]] ## esta parte va
data[data==0]<-NA
test<-data.frame(t(data));test$var<-rownames(test)
test2 <- merge(test, data2, by = "var", all.x = TRUE) 
test3<-data.frame(lapply(test2[2:(ncol(test2)-1)], function(x)x<-ifelse(is.na(x), x, test2$trat)))  
test3<-data.frame(test2$var,test3)
test3<-t(test3)
colnames(test3)<-test3[1,]
test3<-test3[-1,]
```